# Sprites not showing (C# - XNA 4.0)

Tags: xna, c#, textures, sprites

I'm following a tutorial from [XNA GPA](http://xnagpa.net/xna4beginner.php), but in my project, none of the sprites are loading. I've followed all of the instructions exactly, and the code works as expected when I copy it from my project into the example project that he provides.

Here's my Game.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Tutorial
{

    public class Game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Paddle paddle;
        Rectangle screenRectangle;

        public Game()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            screenRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth,
                                            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
        }



        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }


        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            Texture2D tempTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("paddle");
            paddle = new Paddle(tempTexture, screenRectangle);
            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }


        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }


        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            paddle.Update();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }


        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            paddle.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So it runs and nothing happens (no errors)? You get a CornflowerBlue screen?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Set the paddle position to be in the middle of the screen

Comment: Yeah, modify the Paddle.Draw function to draw a texture at coordinates you know are inside the viewport.

Comment: Here's my SetInStartPosition method `private void SetInStartPosition()
        {
            position.X = (screenBounds.Width - texture.Width) / 2;
            position.Y = screenBounds.Width - texture.Width - 5;
        }`

and my Draw() method `public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
        }`

SetInStartPosition() is called in the constructor for paddle so surely this should work?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) method and see if you get expected values. This is probably more a question of how to debug than an XNA question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible problem is in your SetInStartPosition(). For setting the Y position it should be position.Y = screenBounds.**Height** - texture.**Height**... not screenBounds.**Width** - texture.**Width**...